# Notice: Undefined variable: $product *input type image as button

Tags: php, forms, post, undefined, input-type-file

umm... i'm confused from $_GET/$_POST but i often used $_POST n sometimes $_GET for one to one html.. here's my code :

home.php :

```
<form action="buy.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="image" name="product" value="Noodle" src="images/Noodle.jpg" height="290" width="333">
    <input type="image" name="product" value="Rice" src="images/Rice.jpg" height="290" width="333">
    <input type="image" name="product" value="tofu" src="images/tofu.jpg" height="290" width="333">
</form>
```

buy.php :

```
<?php
$product = $_POST["product"];
echo "You have ordered a bowl of ". $product . '!' . " Do you need to get extra beverages?"; ?>
<div>
<form action="main_menu.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="NO">
```

```
<h3> Choose extra Menu </h3>
<form action="extra_menu.php" method="GET"> `
<table bgcolor="#B0D8E2" border="0" cellpadding="2" width="180">
<tr> <td valign="middle">
<input type="image" name="name" value="dumplings" src="images/dumplings.jpg" height="300" width="300">
</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
<table bgcolor="#B0D8E2" border="0" cellpadding="2" width="180">
<tr> 
<td valign="middle"> 
<input type="image" name="name" value="cayenne" src="images/cayenne.jpg " height="300" width="300">
</td></tr> 
</table>
```

main_menu.php :

```
  <?php
echo $product . "your main product will be sent soon!";
?>
```

extra_menu.php :

```
<?php
echo "you have ordered". htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!' . " Please wait a moment!";
?>
```

Only on the main_menu.php i got Notice: Undefined variable: product
i ever tried to add `$product=$_POST["product"];` but still undefined variable x_x
why the variable i defined before cant recognized? 0w0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: how come you have same name for all input types??

Comment: my logic is all the food categorized as product and i spawn them again on main_menu.php to declare which one was ordered... so, what's your idea for making them tidy?

Answer (score 0):

HOME.PHP

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="Noodle"/> 
<input type="image" name="productImg[]"  src="images/Noodle.jpg" height="290" width="333">
<input type="text" name="product[]" value="Rice"/>
<input type="image" name="productImg[]"  src="images/Rice.jpg" height="290" width="333"> 
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

buy.php

```
<?php

$products = $_POST["product"];
foreach($products as $product) {
  echo "You have ordered a bowl of ". $product . '!' . " Do you need to get extra beverages?<BR/>";   
}
?>
<div>
<form action="main_menu.php" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="NO">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: when i used that multipart, my image cant redirect me to the buy.php

Comment: to send that page to buy.php you have to use submit button you have not done any thing to submit in that form

Comment: when i used that multipart, this is my code, still i dunno how to use $_FILES to make my image appears.. <form action="buy.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"/><input type="image" name="product" value="Noodle" src="images/Noodle.jpg" height="290" width="333">
    <input type="image" name="product" value="Rice" src="images/Rice.jpg" height="290" width="333">
</form> Yes it worked now without the submit button, but when i called the $product on my main_menu.php still undefined..

Comment: i try use your code, firstly on the home.php i got two txt bar then i click the submit button.. after that it redirect to buy.php, but with two results 0w0 You have ordered a bowl of Noodle! Do you need to get extra beverages?
You have ordered a bowl of Rice! Do you need to get extra beverages?.. then i click that NO button then it redirect to main_menu.php?SUBMIT=NO with object not found 0w0

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

You need to check if that array key exists in the $_POST superglobal before you set it, otherwise set it to something else.

```
$product = isset( $_POST['product'] ) ? $_POST['product'] : false;
```

Using the above ternary, when you have not posted a `product variable` it will then assign it the value of `false`.

Then later you can check before you echo `$product` by checking the value.

```
if (FALSE !== $product){
    echo $product;
}
```

Comment: i use your code <?php
    $product = isset( $_POST['product'] ) ? $_POST['product'] : false;
    echo $product. "your main product will be sent soon!";
  ?> Yes, the error was gone but the $product wont appear..